# Why Crashlytics don't want to submit ipa?

Tags: ios, ios9, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Does anyone have seen this before?

I have used this command:
`Crashlytics.framework/submit XXX XXX -debug YES -ipaPath Path/to/ipa/exported/from/organizer`

> 2015-10-29 23:52:13.121 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (15)
>   2015-10-29 23:52:13.126 submit Crashlytics: Path to IPA manually provided: xxxx.ipa
>   2015-10-29 23:52:13.587 submit Crashlytics: Unable to find .app in inflated
>   directory
>   2015-10-29 23:52:13.587 submit Crashlytics: Failed to prepare the binary for release

Thank you for the info.

Comment: How do you get the IPA? Is it generated by Xcode or is this some kind of continuous-integration build? I have the same issue, but found out that I really have no *.app folder in my IPA/Payload/... I was copying the payload content from directory one level deeper than I was supposed to.

Comment: I will strongly suggest to use fastlane (https://fastlane.tools) to pushes ipas to fabric/appstore